# Gzip compression and decompression in C#

Tags: c#, gzip

I'm trying to compress an string in one module and decompressing it in another module. Here is the code I'm using.

Compress

```
public static string CompressString(string text)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
         zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

    byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(gzBuffer);
}
```

Decompress

```
public static byte[] DecompressString(byte[] data)
{
   using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
   using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
     using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
        zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
        return resultStream.ToArray();
     }
}
```

Using it as:

```
 DecompressString(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ip));
```

But, for above statement, I'm getting following error.

> {"The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are
>   passing in a GZip stream."}   System.SystemException
>   {System.IO.InvalidDataException}

Comment: Uhm, you're base64 encoding the result of compression but you're not decoding it before decompressing?

Comment: Indeed - `DecompressString(Convert.FromBase64String(ip));` would make more sense. (Although I'd also suggest that your methods should be symmetric, e.g. make them both accept and return strings, or maybe `byte[] Compress(string)` and `string Decompress(byte[])`.

Comment: Additionally you're stuffing in the length of the compressed data at the start of those bytes, you need to remove those as well before decompressing. Additionally it would make more sense to store the length of the uncompressed data, to handle slight problems at the end of decompression.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a rewrite of your code that should work the way you want it to.

I wrote it in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) and it can be tested in that.

Note that there's very little error checking here. You should add checks to see if all read operations complete and has actually read what they were supposed to and similar checks.

**The output**

```
original: 256
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.  

compressed: 56
AAEAAB+LCAAAAAAABAALycgsVgCiRIWS1OISPYWQEcYHANU9d5YAAQAA 

decompressed: 256
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
```

**The program**

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "This is a test. This is a test. ";
    input += input;
    input += input;
    input += input;
    string compressed = Compress(input);
    string decompressed = Decompress(compressed);

    input.Dump("original: " + input.Length);
    compressed.Dump("compressed: " + compressed.Length);
    decompressed.Dump("decompressed: " + decompressed.Length);
}

public static string Decompress(string input)
{
    byte[] compressed = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    byte[] decompressed = Decompress(compressed);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
}

public static string Compress(string input)
{
    byte[] encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] compressed = Compress(encoded);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(compressed);
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
{
    using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
        source.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);

        var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
        using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(source,
            CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            var result = new byte[length];
            decompressionStream.Read(result, 0, length);
            return result;
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] Compress(byte[] input)
{
    using (var result = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(input.Length);
        result.Write(lengthBytes, 0, 4);

        using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(result,
            CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            compressionStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
            compressionStream.Flush();

        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm not positive that you need to write out the length of the uncompressed data before the compressed data. With some compression methods the last byte or code can be interpreted as more data if you try to read more data than was present when compressing, due to leftover bits, but I'm not sure this holds for gzip, so that part may be unnecessary.

Comment: In fact testing by padding from 1 to 1000 additional characters to the end of the input seems to suggest this is not needed. Someone that knows gzip would have to comment though.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 6+ solution (with fix of https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64577):

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "This is a test. This is a test. ";
    input += input;
    input += input;
    input += input;
    string compressed = Compress(input);
    string decompressed = Decompress(compressed);

    input.Dump("original: " + input.Length);
    compressed.Dump("compressed: " + compressed.Length);
    decompressed.Dump("decompressed: " + decompressed.Length);
}

public static string Decompress(string input)
{
    byte[] compressed = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    byte[] decompressed = Decompress(compressed);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
}

public static string Compress(string input)
{
    byte[] encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] compressed = Compress(encoded);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(compressed);
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
{
    using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
        source.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);

        var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
        using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(source,
            CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            var result = new byte[length];
            int totalRead = 0, bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = decompressionStream.Read(result, totalRead, length - totalRead)) > 0)
            {
              totalRead += bytesRead;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] Compress(byte[] input)
{
    using (var result = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(input.Length);
        result.Write(lengthBytes, 0, 4);

        using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(result,
            CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            compressionStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
            compressionStream.Flush();

        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be good to explain the differences and reasoning in the answer, and for .NET 6 use `Span` where possible/meaningful.

Comment: :-( You copied Lasse V. Karlsen's entire [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135871/1633949) -- replacing only one line -- without giving him any credit. Why? It leaves the false impression that this is all your own work.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution that produced compressed strings which could be decoded by standard utilities such as https://bugdays.com/gzip-base64. The previous solutions don't (presumably due to the non-standard, prepended length value that Lasse mentioned).

I looked at the Microsoft docs for GZipStream, and based on that example code, and the previous solutions presented here by Lasse V. Karlsen and DaGrisa, I came up with the following solution which works nicely (tested in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)):

**The output**

```
original: 256
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. 

compressed: 52
H4sIAAAAAAAACgvJyCxWAKJEhZLU4hI9hZARxgcA1T13lgABAAA=

decompressed: 256
This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
```

**The program**

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "This is a test. This is a test. ";
    input += input;
    input += input;
    input += input;
    string compressed = Compress(input);
    string decompressed = Decompress(compressed);

    input.Dump("original: " + input.Length);
    compressed.Dump("compressed: " + compressed.Length);
    decompressed.Dump("decompressed: " + decompressed.Length);
}

public static string Decompress(string input)
{
    byte[] compressed = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    byte[] decompressed = Decompress(compressed);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
}

public static string Compress(string input)
{
    byte[] encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] compressed = Compress(encoded);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(compressed);
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
{
    using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        using (var result = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var Decompress = new GZipStream(source, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                Decompress.CopyTo(result);
            }

            return result.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] Compress(byte[] input)
{
    using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        using (var result = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var Compress = new GZipStream(result, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                source.CopyTo(Compress);
            }
            
            return result.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```